# Internet Explorer 11 addons don't work

Tags: internet-explorer, addons

I can't enable third-party addons like LastPass or Adblock Plus on Internet Explorer 11 because the options for toggling them are greyed out. Only Microsoft addons work. I've reinstalled IE twice, but it didn't help.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.  The computer is my desktop PC; no network and I'm the only user.

Comment: We will need more information.  This a personal or company device?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you have admin rights being that you've uninstalled and re-installed IE, however based on your description it seems that there are group policies being applied to your account. Is your computer a domain joined computer?
You can run the following from the command prompt to view all the group policies being applied to both your user account and computer account:

```
GPRESULT /H FilesName.HTML
```

Comment: It's tough being a new user who wants to help, but is hindered by lack of rep.  I see another answer got dinged.  So that you understand, Super User isn't a forum.  Its purpose is to build a knowledgebase, which relies on the structure of questions being questions and answers being definitive solutions to the questions.  Speculative solutions, helpful hints, or clarifying questions go in comments, which requires a little more rep.  I'll copy this to a comment.  Then if you delete the answer, any downvotes will also be deleted.

Comment: I just deleted the comment because it looks like it was a good guess but not applicable in this case.  According to the OP, it is a single-user PC that isn't in a networked environment.  (another risk of speculative answers -- if you guess wrong, the answer will be wrong and people will downvote it.)

Comment: @fixer1234 - While they will be downvoted they will still count against his overall ability to post answers.  He should instead resolve the problems with the answer.